# Reading excel column 1 into Python dictionary key, column 2 into value

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

I have an excel sheet containing the following:

```
 Column1  Column2
 A        1
 B        2
 C        3
 D        4
```

I would like to read the sheet into a Python dictionary with:

```
Key :   Value
A   :   1
B   :   2
C   :   3
D   :   4
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Hmm...did you try something?

Comment: Yes, I have :

    dict_list = []
     for row_index in xrange(1, sheet.nrows):
        d = {keys[col_index]: sheet.cell(row_index, col_index).value 
             for col_index in xrange(sheet.ncols)}
        dict_list.append(d)

But I'd like it to run on the other axis

Comment: I'd recommend use *[edit]* instead of comment, it's not readable in comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `xlrd` module as follows:

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(r"input.xlsx")
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

col_a = sheet.col_values(0, 1)
col_b = sheet.col_values(1, 1)

my_dict = {a : b for a, b in zip(col_a, col_b)}

print my_dict
```

This will display the following output for your given data:

```
{u'A': 1.0, u'C': 3.0, u'B': 2.0, u'D': 4.0}
```

It first creates a list for each of the columns, skipping the `Column A` row at the top. It then uses Python's `zip` command and a dictionary comprehension to build a dictionary with each pair of column values.